Is it grammatically correct to use food is tasty as an abbreviation for food's tasty?
Question 1)
Is it grammatically correct to use food is tasty as an abbreviation for food's tasty?
Question 2) Read the text and write answers to the questions in complete English sentences, including subject and verb.


The blue text is the answer I wrote, but indicate itself has the meaning of indicating a signal or clue, so when used with cue, it was treated as an incorrect answer as a duplicate expression.
The score was 4 points, but I was given 0 points.
Of course, I admit that it is grammatically incorrect because it is a duplicate expression, but couldn't I receive at least partial credit?
Thank you for your answer in advance.

I would ask the teacher to explain, since your answer seems reasonable and is taken directly from the text. Maybe there were instructions that insist that you use your own words? (Is that what you mean by "duplicate expression," that you must not duplicate any words from the original text? Note, there's nothing "grammatically incorrect" about doing so.) Or maybe the teacher just made a mistake.

It is a cue. It doesn't indicate a cue. It is a cue that the food is tasty.  It indicates that the food is tasty. or It is an indication that the food is tasty.

@TimR And I avoided diving into the fact that "cue" is a slightly odd choice of word here, and is present only because the original text used it in a preceding sentence.

What @AndyBonner said. cue is at the very least an odd choice here (perhaps the writer is getting confused with clue). And as TimR says, indicates is another odd choice, regardless of whether we use cue or clue (because that's what it is, not what's indicated). Personally, I wouldn't contract food is, but it's not an unreasonable stylistic choice.

@AndyBonner  Yes, in the sense of following the group as discussed in the contextual paragraph, it is a behavioral cue.

"Food's tasty" is an abbreviation (technically a contraction) of "Food is tasty". It's very common but it's informal. You would not use it in formal writing.
As for any other issues: we do not do proofreading of text, and we don't know what the marker is thinking. You will have to ask your teacher why you got the score you did.

I won't disagree with this except to the extent that I would not call it an abbreviation, but rather a contraction - it is common in informal English to contract "X is «adjective» to "X's «adjective»".

Good point. I wanted to use the same word the questioner did.
